# How to set time gap while navigate from one view to other view

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

How to set time gap while navigate from one view to other view ,Can anyone please help me out to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: whether u want to navigate programmatically or on user selection.?

Comment: @vishy while user tap button it navigate to other view,i want to make slow motion while Goin